# MongoDB Accessor singleton doesn't compile unless I include "grpcpp/grpcpp.h"

Tags: c++, mongodb, grpc, mongo-cxx-driver

I have stumbled upon a slightly odd problem

My mongodb singleton is slightly modified from the version seen [here.](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/master/examples/mongocxx/instance_management.cpp)

```
// mongodb_access.h
#include <mongocxx/client.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/instance.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/logger.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/pipeline.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/pool.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/uri.hpp>

#include <bsoncxx/stdx/make_unique.hpp>
#include <bsoncxx/stdx/optional.hpp>
#include <bsoncxx/stdx/string_view.hpp>

class mongodb_access {
public:
  static mongodb_access &instance() {
    static mongodb_access instance;
    return instance;
  }

  void configure(std::unique_ptr<mongocxx::instance> instance,
                 std::unique_ptr<mongocxx::pool> pool) {
    _instance = std::move(instance);
    _pool = std::move(pool);
  }

  using connection = mongocxx::pool::entry;

  connection get_connection() { return _pool->acquire(); }

  bsoncxx::stdx::optional<connection> try_get_connection() {
    return _pool->try_acquire();
  }

private:
  mongodb_access() = default;

  std::unique_ptr<mongocxx::instance> _instance = nullptr;
  std::unique_ptr<mongocxx::pool> _pool = nullptr;
};

inline void configure(mongocxx::uri uri) {
  class noop_logger : public mongocxx::logger {
  public:
    virtual void operator()(mongocxx::log_level, bsoncxx::stdx::string_view,
                            bsoncxx::stdx::string_view) noexcept {}
  };

  auto instance = bsoncxx::stdx::make_unique<mongocxx::instance>(
      bsoncxx::stdx::make_unique<noop_logger>());

  mongodb_access::instance().configure(
      std::move(instance),
      bsoncxx::stdx::make_unique<mongocxx::pool>(std::move(uri)));
}
```

I configure the uri from one of my translation units (one which is created first) and then I use `auto conn = mongodb_access::instance().get_connection();` to get the connection where I need it.

For example :

```
// foo.cpp

#include "grpcpp/grpcpp.h" // <- This is needed for some reason
#include "mongodb_access.h"

#include "bsoncxx/builder/basic/array.hpp"
#include "bsoncxx/builder/basic/document.hpp"
#include "bsoncxx/builder/basic/kvp.hpp"
#include "bsoncxx/json.hpp"
#include "bsoncxx/types.hpp"
#include "mongocxx/exception/exception.hpp"

class foo
{

foo()
{
    // configure db connections
  auto uri = mongocxx::uri{mongocxx::uri::k_default_uri};
  configure(std::move(uri));
}

void some_random_function()
{
    auto conn = mongodb_access::instance().get_connection();
    /// ...
}

}
```

This does not compile unless I add in `grpcpp/grpcpp.h` from `grpc` as the first import (or atleast before including `mongodb_access.h`)

If I don't, I get a bunch of errors :

```
[build] D:\Libs\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\mongocxx/options/find.hpp(216,11): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max' 
[build] D:\Libs\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\mongocxx/options/find.hpp(216,11): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'max' 
[build] D:\Libs\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\mongocxx/options/find.hpp(216,11): error C3646: 'max': unknown override specifier 
[build] D:\Libs\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\mongocxx/options/find.hpp(216,11): error C2059: syntax error: ')' 
[build] D:\Libs\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\mongocxx/options/find.hpp(216,11): error C2098: unexpected token after data member 'view_or_value' 
[build] D:\Libs\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\mongocxx/options/find.hpp(216,11): error C2059: syntax error: '>' 
[build] D:\Libs\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\mongocxx/options/find.hpp(216,11): error C2059: syntax error: '?' 
[build] D:\Libs\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\mongocxx/options/find.hpp(216,11): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding ':'; skipping apparent function body 

... and many others
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like your typical side-effect from include pollution, and most likely has nothing to do with grpc itself. One of the headers that grpc includes is solving your issue that is. You could try narrowing it down using gcc -E to show the preprocessed code. My gut feeling says you're missing .